# Using case-when in aggregate function in Sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Is it possible to build the below query on a Model instead of using sequilize.query() for raw sql

```sql
select 
  queue,
  count(*) total,
  sum(case when type = 'Proactive' then 1 else 0 end) proactive,
  sum(case when type = 'Reactive' then 1 else 0 end) reactive
from "OpenIncidents" 
group by queue
order by total DESC;
```

I tired using sequelize.fn() for aggregate function, but found nothing in the docs regarding CASE WHEN support in aggregate function.

I currently using raw query

```
return sequelize.query(
    `
    SELECT 
      queue, 
      COUNT(*) total, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Proactive' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) proactive, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Reactive' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) reactive 
    FROM "OpenIncidents" 
    GROUP BY queue 
    ORDER BY total DESC;
    `, 
    { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
  .then(queues => res.json(queues))
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
```

Is there any way to do it directly on a Sequelize Model, like below

```
return OpenIncident.findAll({
  attributes:[
    'queue',
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('id')), 'total'],
    [sequelize.fn('SUM', CASE_WHEN_STATEMENT, 'proactive'],
    [sequelize.fn('SUM', CASE_WHEN_STATEMENT), 'reactive']
  ],
  group: ['queue'],
  order: [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('id')), 'DESC']
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use `Sequelize.literal()', as shown below:

```
[Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.literal('CASE WHEN type = 'Proactive' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END')), 'proactive']
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are running into issues with the parsing following should work as of Dec 2022 Sequelize version.

```
[sequelize.fn('SUM', sequelize.literal("CASE WHEN status = 'PENDING' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END")), 'pending_count'],
```