# Using case-when in aggregate function on included model in Sequelize.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Inspired from the answer : [Using case-when in aggregate function in Sequelize.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379980/using-case-when-in-aggregate-function-in-sequelize-js) I wanna *agregate* on multiple cases with `SUM` according to the type of like I have.

Here is the `MySQL` *query raw* I wanna **convert** into `Sequelize` :

```sql
SELECT 
    article.*,
    SUM(case when isLike = TRUE then 1 else 0 end) likes,
    SUM(case when isLike = FALSE then 1 else 0 end) dislikes
FROM article
LEFT JOIN articleLike ON articleLike.articleId = article.id
group by article.id
order by article.id;
```

I've already tried many things in Sequelize adding also paginaton in my options and my closest answer is :

```js
await Article.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: ArticleLike,
          as: "likes",
          attributes: []
        },
      ],
      attributes: [
        [
          Sequelize.fn(
            "SUM",
            Sequelize.literal("CASE WHEN likes.isLike = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END")
          ),
          "nbLikes",
        ],
        [
          Sequelize.fn(
            "SUM",
            Sequelize.literal(
              "CASE WHEN likes.isLike = FALSE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END"
            )
          ),
          "nbDislikes",
        ],
      ],
      offset: 0,
      limit: 9,
      group: "id",
      order: [["id"]],
    });
```

Nevertheless, it doesn't work and give me the error :

```
Unknown column 'likes.isLike' in 'field list'
```

The default generated SQL query before throwing the error :

```sql
Executing (default):
SELECT `article`.*
FROM (SELECT `article`.`id`, SUM(CASE WHEN likes.isLike = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `nbLikes`, SUM(CASE WHEN likes.isLike = FALSE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `nbDislikes` FROM `article` AS `article` GROUP BY `id` ORDER BY `article`.`id` LIMIT 0, 9) AS `article`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `articleLike` AS `likes` ON `article`.`id` = `likes`.`articleId`
ORDER BY `article`.`id`;
```

Oddly, my Sequelize request works if `limit` and `offset` are absent in my options object.

The following works (without all attributes in `article`) :

```js
await Article.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: ArticleLike,
          as: "likes",
          attributes: []
        },
      ],
      attributes: [
        [
          Sequelize.fn(
            "SUM",
            Sequelize.literal("CASE WHEN likes.isLike = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END")
          ),
          "nbLikes",
        ],
        [
          Sequelize.fn(
            "SUM",
            Sequelize.literal(
              "CASE WHEN likes.isLike = FALSE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END"
            )
          ),
          "nbDislikes",
        ],
      ],
      // none of limit and offset
      group: "id",
      order: [["id"]],
    });
```

Which gives me the result below :

```
--- 0 // article 0 with his num of likes dislikes
nbLikes "2"
nbDislikes  "1"
--- 1 // article 1 with his num of likes dislikes
nbLikes "2"
nbDislikes  "1"
--- 2  // article 2 with his num of likes dislikes
nbLikes "2"
nbDislikes  "1"
```

Can someone please help me figuring out ?